# IoT Hub Event does not receive Azure device twin updated recorded property

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid

IoT Hub Event does not receive recorded property changes in the device twin. For example, property ledState is updated by the actual device (with patch) and the device twin updates the reported property, but the IoT Hub Event does not receive the event. This limits me in passing this property change to a digital twin with an azure function.

The IoT Hub Event does not show updated properties, unlike telemetry which IoT Hub Event receives. Considering IoT Hub Event only receives Device Created, Deleted, Connected, Disconnected, Telemetry Event Types.

How can I get IoT Hub Events to subscribe to property updates?

Further description:

The actual device sends packet (MQTT function _nxd_mqtt_client_publish_packet_send) and I can see this logged in Termite: $iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/reported/?$rid=1121{"ledState":true} . The hub successfully responds with 204.

This is my device as shown in IoT hub and the device's ledState (reported) property is updated to true when I press button A in mxchip:

[image]

```js
{
"deviceId": "mxchip",

"etag": "AAAAAAAAAF8=",
"deviceEtag": "NDY5NTIxODE1",
"status": "enabled",
"statusUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"connectionState": "Connected",
"lastActivityTime": "2022-09-16T14:51:32.9293466Z",
"cloudToDeviceMessageCount": 0,
"authenticationType": "sas",
"x509Thumbprint": {
    "primaryThumbprint": null,
    "secondaryThumbprint": null
},
"modelId": "dtmi:azurertos:devkit:gsgmxchip;2",
"version": 5310,
"properties": {
    "desired": {
        "telemetryInterval": 5,
        "$metadata": {
            "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T12:44:24.4494023Z",
            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 95,
            "telemetryInterval": {
                "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T12:44:24.4494023Z",
                "$lastUpdatedVersion": 95
            }
        },
        "$version": 95
    },
    "reported": {
        "deviceInformation": {
            "__t": "c",
            "manufacturer": "MXCHIP",
            "model": "AZ3166",
            "swVersion": "1.0.0",
            "osName": "Azure RTOS",
            "processorArchitecture": "Arm Cortex M4",
            "processorManufacturer": "STMicroelectronics",
            "totalStorage": 1024,
            "totalMemory": 128
        },
        "ledState": true,
        "telemetryInterval": {
            "ac": 200,
            "av": 1,
            "value": 5
        },
        "$metadata": {
            "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T14:55:52.6321409Z",
            "deviceInformation": {
                "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z",
                "__t": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "manufacturer": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "model": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "swVersion": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "osName": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "processorArchitecture": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "processorManufacturer": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "totalStorage": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                },
                "totalMemory": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:57.5894378Z"
                }
            },
            "ledState": {
                "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T14:55:52.6321409Z"
            },
            "telemetryInterval": {
                "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:58.1675571Z",
                "ac": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:58.1675571Z"
                },
                "av": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:58.1675571Z"
                },
                "value": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-09-16T13:54:58.1675571Z"
                }
            }
        },
        "$version": 5215
    }
},
"capabilities": {
    "iotEdge": false
}
}
```

I have commented out telemetry messages in the code so only recorded property changes are sent to IoT hub but property changes don't show for Events:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding the question, but it seems you're trying to get an **Event Grid Subscription** on a Twin Change event. The short answer is: you can't. Device Twin events are not supported for Event Grid.

> How can I get IoT Hub Events to subscribe to property updates?

You mentioned that you want Device Twin changes sent to an Azure Function, you can do that by leveraging Endpoints and Message Routing. You can configure Message Routing to do that in this way:
[[image: A screenshot of the Message Routing screen]

The **endpoint** can be:

- An Azure Event Hub
- An Azure Service Bus Queue
- An Azure Service Bus Topic
- Blob Storage

All of these can be used as an input to your Azure Function.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet shows an example of simple *IoTHubTrigger* publisher function to Azure Event Grid Custom Topic.

```csharp
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

static HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AEG_CustomTopic1")) };

public static async Task Run(string myIoTHubMessage, IDictionary<string, object> properties, IDictionary<string, object> systemProperties, ILogger log)
{   
    log.LogInformation($"\nProperties: \n\t{string.Join(" | ", properties.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}");
    log.LogInformation($"\nSystemProperties: \n\t{string.Join(" | ", systemProperties.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}");
    log.LogInformation(myIoTHubMessage); 

    // select only twinChangeEvents
    //if((string)systemProperties["iothub-message-source"] != "twinChangeEvents")
    //   return;

    // Fire event
    var ege = new { 
         id=$"{systemProperties["Offset"]}", 
         subject=$"devices/{systemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]}", 
         eventType=$"{systemProperties["iothub-message-source"]}", 
         eventTime=systemProperties["iothub-enqueuedtime"], 
         data= new { properties = properties, systemProperties = systemProperties.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>$"{x.Value}"), body = JObject.Parse(myIoTHubMessage)}, 
         dataVersion="1.0"
         };
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", new[] { ege } );
    log.LogInformation($"FireEvent: {response.StatusCode}");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

function.json:

```csharp
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "myIoTHubMessage",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "******",
      "connection": "******",
      "consumerGroup": "function",
      "cardinality": "one"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note, that the above function uses a REST POST request (no output AEG binding) to fire an event to the Azure Event Grid via a Custom Topic.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful guidance by @Matthijs van der Veer ! I ended up doing this and can now capture digital twin change events. Expanded answer in case it helps anyone:

1. Created Event Hub -> create event hub instance. Then create Share Access Policy for this instance to receive mssgs.
2. Create Event Hub Trigger function app. Added nugget pckg Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace BladeFunctionApps
    {
        public static class 
    DeviceTwinSendAndReceivePropertyToEventHub
    {
        [FunctionName("DeviceTwinSendPropertyToEventHub")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("robo-eventhub", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {eventData.EventBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
            {
                log.LogInformation("WE have exceptions:" + exceptions.Count);
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
            }

            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
            {
                log.LogInformation("WE have exceptions:" + exceptions.Count);
                throw exceptions.Single();
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }
3. Added to IotHub a message route: select Event Hub in message route and create and endpoint from the event hub instance shared access policy. Then create route for digital twin changes to route these to the end point.